# iOS Core plot - graph line not extending upto major interval

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am new to **CorePlot**. I am trying to render a graph that pulls data across network every 10 seconds. I want to plot the data that's pulled every 10 seconds and so I've set x.majorIntervalLength as 10. I expect every plot to appear on the major ticks, however, that's not how it works.

If my x-axis is 12:10:10 12:10:20 12:10:30 12:10:40 and so on, first plot occurs at 12:10:10, however second one happens 12:10:11 , third at 12:10:12 and so on. I expect the second and third plot symbols to appear at 12:10:20 and 12:10:30 because thats when the data is pulled from the backend.

Here's my x-axis configuration:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@" HH:mm:ss\rYYYY.MM.dd"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

CPTTimeFormatter *dateTimeFormatterForXAxis = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] ;
dateTimeFormatterForXAxis.referenceDate = [NSDate date];
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
x.labelFormatter = dateTimeFormatterForXAxis;
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
x.majorIntervalLength   = @10;
```

What am I missing here?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time intervals are in seconds, so you should multiply the index by 10 to space the data points 10 seconds apart.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Eric. I multiplied the axis index appropriately and it works.